# How to terminate an infinite recursion sequence in Bison?

Tags: bison, yacc

I'm new to Bison and struggling to understand how to represent "one or more" or "zero or more" (i.e. + and * in regex).

I'm trying to produce a grammar like:

> word word ... word;

However, I'm not sure where I ought to terminate the recursive sequence. Anywhere I intuitively think I should place some terminator-token causes shift conflicts.

So far I've managed to create the grammar:

```
word_list 
    : word { printf("parsed first word: %s\n", $1); }
    | word_list word { printf("parsed following: %s\n", $2); };

word : WORD { $$ = $1; }
```

This is almost where I want it:

**Input**: `this is something;`
**Output**:

```
parsed first word: this
parsed following: is
parsed following: something
```

If I continue entering input, it always takes the path of `| word_list word`, so how can I designate a token to, essentially, break out of this recursion?

Do I need to subsequently wrap word_list in another non-terminal that specifies a termination sequence for it or what?

I'm essentially trying to produce a linked-list of whatever is considered as a *word* as the top-level parser generation (i.e. hoping I can concatenate lists at higher-level non-terminals and let `%start` return a single list).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion will end naturally when something other than a `WORD` is encountered; you don't need to do anything. Of course, for the parse to be successful, the next token must be in `word_list`'s FOLLOW set.